# Gunicorn Timeout - How to increase timeout?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, gunicorn

I have python fastapi deployed using gunicorn. Request gets timed out exactly after 1min.

```
504 Gateway Time-out
```

I want to increase the timeout of api due to long backend processing. Tried to pass time out as below but it does not work at all.

```
gunicorn main:app --keep-alive 300 -w 3 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 300
```

Is it correct way to pass timeout value? How can i fix it ?

Comment: Are you using nginx or another server in front of your application? It's probably that server generating the 504 error?

Comment: I was able to fix it after updating timeout in nginx deployments configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "600"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
```

Adding above configuration in deployments files fixed the issues.